# Visa free multiple entry into the Philippines

Tags: visas, swedish-citizens

I'm a Swedish citizen and in January I visited the Philippines for ten days using their 30 day visa free stay.

In June I'm planning to visit the Philippines for 21 days. Will I need a tourist visa for that? Official sources are not clear on this, when you leave and come back. I have renewed my passport since my last trip as my old one would expire in less than 6 months after my arrival date for the June trip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you worried that the January visit makes you ineligible for the visa-free stay for your next visit? I'm not sure if there's somewhere that states that, but neither the official immigration site or the tourism site says anything about this:

[Immigration.gov.ph FAQ page](http://www.immigration.gov.ph/index.php/faqs/travel-req):

> If you are a foreign national from a country with diplomatic ties or bilateral agreement with the Philippines, you are allowed to enter the country without securing an entry visa and will be given an initial stay of thirty (30) days provided that you are a holder of a passport valid for at least six (6) months beyond your contemplated stay in the Philippines and present a return or onward ticket.

[Tourism.gov.ph Immigration and Customs page](http://www.tourism.gov.ph/SitePages/customs.aspx):

> Nationals from countries (click list) who are travelling to the Philippines for business and tourism purposes are allowed to enter the Philippines without visas for a stay not exceeding twenty-one (21) days, provided they hold valid tickets for their return journey to port of origin or next port of destination and their passports valid for a period of at least six (6) months beyond the contemplated period of stay. However, Immigration Officers at ports of entry may exercise their discretion to admit holders of passports valid for at least sixty (60) days beyond the intended period of stay.

Sweden is on the list of countries who's citizens can stay visa-free (as you've already proved).

Those are the most authoritative sources, for a less authoritative source I know people (both EU and US citizens) who visit the Philippines far more frequently that every six months on the visa-free system and never have a problem. I did it myself before I had a long-term Philippine visa.

As long as you have a valid ticket out the country (which immigration rarely ask for or check -- but your airline likely will) and have not had issues with overstaying or being removed from the Philippines in the past then there will be no issue.

Occasionally, there can be an issue if you stay for a very long time and repeatedly leave for a day or two simply to restart the visa-free clock. But this is not true in your case and you really have to stay a long time and do it **a lot** for anyone to notice. And mostly it's because they want you to pay for the correct long term visa extension.

Comment: Indeed, I'm mostly worried about the time I stay doesn't reset.

Comment: @OnePie It definitely does reset. Each entry gives you a new 30 days. This is checked by examining your most recent entry stamp when you leave (although I imagine their computer also tracks it). I agree it's not explicit but it's each 'stay' that must be less than the limit, if that wasn't the case the language on the sites I quoted would make it explicit that the time is cumulative over some period.